# Is there a way to translate the title in the configuration section of an octobercms page

Tags: php, laravel, localization, translation, octobercms

I installed rainlab translation plugin and it's working well for the twigg translation with

```
{{ "text to translate"|_ }}
```

Also, I know we can easily create lang folder in plugins and us it this way:

```
'name' => 'Traductions',
```

I also translated my url this way in my page configuration:

```
[viewBag]
localeUrl[en] = "/clinics/slug"
```

But is it possible to do something similar for titles?
I need to translate the page title in the php / configuration section of the page.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can utilize code section

and put this code

```
url = "/blog"
layout = "default"
==
<?
function onEnd() {
    $this->page->title = <<Your Translated Title>>;
} 
?>
==
<h3>Html Here</h3>
```

(assuming you are using rainlab translate plugin)To translate messages you can use

```
use RainLab\Translate\Models\Message;
```

then

```
$this->page->title = Message::trans($string, $params);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! It works. It's important to mention that is has to be in the "onEnd()" function in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it properly with the right tools, developing a translatable website won't take much longer with October's Plugin.

With translate plugin the languague can be especified as part of the URL and you will be able to use Twig filter with less effort.

Check this:
http://octobercms.com/blog/post/building-responsive-multi-language-website-blog-and-static-pages